# How to make a weekly timetable in python using pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Can someone help me in identifying the tools needed in pyqt5 to make a similar weekly timetable to the image below where I can edit,add and remove data that is inputed.

I need to be pointed in the right direction of what I should use to approach in making this program, what should I use to create something similar.

[image]

Comment: [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) (and maybe [QCalendar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendar.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could create a QGridLayout, and add multiple QLabel's to it, make these editable with setEditable(True), and whenever the user edits the label, write the value to a dictionary. When the application quits, you have to save the timetable to a file; here, json.dump could be useful (it converts a dict to json and writes that to a file). On application startup, you can load the data again with json.load (it reads a json file and converts the json to a dict) and set the values on the labels.